# Can I reimport a deleated .git file without loosing code?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I deleted my .git file from my project. But, I haven't deleted my project folder. Can I still import ONLY .git file without reimporting the whole project?

I haven't tried anything I don't want to lose the code I have when deleting the folder and reimporting the complete project

Comment: your question is unclear. .git is a directory not a file, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recover a file/folder from your system you need to look for some **recovery tools**.

But here is the steps, how you can save your uncommitted effort safely:

> 1- clone your project into another folder.
>
> 2- you will have the latest code with `.git` stuffs.
>
> 3- copy paste all files from old folder to new.
>
> 4- now you have overwritten only those files which are having change.
>
> 5- run `git status` to see the efforts intact.

Alternatively:

> 1- clone your project into another folder.
>
> 2- you will have the latest code with `.git` stuffs.
>
> 3- copy paste all `.git` stuffs from new folder to older.
>
> 4- now you have `git` back into your project.
>
> 5- run `git status` to see the efforts intact.

Answer (score 0):

.git is the directory which maintains the version control for your source code. Delelting this does not affect to your source code + local changes.
If you need the git version control back again, easiest thing you could do is get a fresh clone of the remote repository and use a merging tool(ex:winmerge, araxis merge) from which you can identify your local changes) and then you can do a commit